# Enviar valores de view to controller por jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, .net

Eu estou fazendo uma aplicação em .Net C#, e queria fazer um input e um botão que enviasse as informações para minha `controller` por `jquery/ajax`, e eu não faço a mínima ideia de como realizar isso, eu preciso passar as informações por `ajax` pra `controller`.

*Minha* `controller` *chama BarCodeController e e a rota e BarCode/BarGenerate*

Segue em baixo minha `controller`

```
public ActionResult BarGenerate(string Barconteudo)
{
    var BarObj = new QRCodeModel();
        BarObj.barconteudo = Barconteudo;

    return View(BarObj);
}
```

Comment: Qual é o nome da sua `Controller` ou a rota até a sua `Action`? Se você está enviando um dado por ajax, não deveria retornar uma view como resultado...

Comment: Minha controller chama BarCodController e e a rota e BarCode/BarGenerate

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

**View:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="Barconteudo" id="Barconteudo" />
    <input type="text" name="Teste" id="Teste" />
    <input type="button" btn="myBtn" value="Enviar" onclick="enviaInformacoes()" />
</form>
<script>
    function enviaInformacoes() {
        var objeto = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/BarCode/BarGenerate",
            type: "POST",
            data: objeto,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Mensagem);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult BarGenerate(QRCodeModel model)
{
    return Json(new { Mensagem = $"{model.Barconteudo} - {model.Teste}" });
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class QRCodeModel 
{
    public string Barconteudo { get; set; }
    public string Teste { get; set; }
}
```

**Explicação:**

Temos dois `inputs` um com `name` e `ID` **Barconteudo** outro **Teste** e um botão que ao ser clicado chama a função `enviaInformacoes()`.

Na função, com `JQuery` é feito um `serialize` do `form` que faz com que todos campos sejam "jogados" em um objeto(vai criar um objeto com os campos Barconteudo e Teste), após isso, com `$.ajax` é indicado a `URL`, o tipo(Post ou Get), os dados a serem enviados, o tipo(json) e caso haja sucesso na requisição é emitido um alerta com o campo "Mensagem".

No `controller` foi alterado para receber um objeto do tipo **QRCodeModel** que contem as propriedades **Barconteudo** e **Teste**. além do tipo de retorno que foi alterado para `Json` com o campo "Mensagem"

Comment: e se eu tiver mais e 1 campo, do tipo BarObj.barconteudo = Barconteudo;
e
BarObj.teste = Teste;

Comment: Vou editar com múltiplos campos, mas nesse caso você pode, ou passar campo a campo como parâmetro ou criar um objeto